# How to load the online pictures with"<IMG src=cid:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx" in HTML (email content)

Tags: java, html, email

I am writing a android based Mail Client without the Javamail API but just the sockets and IMAP protocol. When I got the html text of the mail and used webview to display it but the embedded picture didn't be rendered by webview. I checked the text of this html found that in the IMG field the tag is IMG src=cid:xxxxxxx@xxxxxx".

```
<img src="cid:67030166@D05EAF17.0F0E4E58.jpg"
```

So do you have some ideas to solve it,I don't want to download the pic and swap the cid:xxxxx@xxx into a local url.

I browsed many blogs they told me that the cid:xxxx@xxxx is the content_id of the base64 attachment  but I didn't get any content_id of the attachment by using the IMAP command :

```
toServer.writeBytes("A003 FETCH * body[2])\n");
```

And used the body structure there were still no cids.